# Android Studio System.out.println not working

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I've been trying to figure out what went wrong for an hour now with this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        botao.setOnClickListener(v -> System.out.println("Button pressed"));
    }
}
```

It's simply supposed to print that. But the console won't show anything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried creating a simple method to use on the OnClick attribute. But still It does not work.

Comment: probably just a *translation* problem, but `button` != `botao`

Comment: It's probably there. It's just hard to notice sometimes. As the answer suggests, use `Log.x`, and then you can use the filter. I think you can use the filter to find the `System.out`, but It has been so long since I messed with Android that I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print to your console, try this:

```java
Log.d("MainActivity", "Button pressed");
```

Instead of:

```java
System.out.println("Button pressed")
```

Tell me if that helps you !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To print to Logcat you can use:

```
    Log.d(TAG,"your_massage");
```

For displaying "Button pressed" when pressing the button, try:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   messageTextView.setText("Button pressed");
}
```

and add a message TextView in xml.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `System.out.println` you should use Logcat or Toast message. here is descriptions for logcat and toast messages.

1. Logcat

   `Log.i("example", "Hello, World !");`

- in there we use *i* for the info category. If you want to make it to error message, then use the `Log.e`
- the first string "example" is your tag. For see the message enter your tag in Logcat. you can rename your tag with any word that you want.
- the second string "Hello, World !" is your message. Type the message that you want to show the user.

2. Toast Message

   `Toast.makeText(this, "Hello, World !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

- in here we use `this` for context.
- the second string "Hello, World !" is your message.
- the third parameter `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`is the time of the message. if you want to make it longer, the use the `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`